# PHP - Put variables with a prefix into array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any way of putting variables into an array? I'm not really sure how else to explain it.

I'm developing a website that works with a game server.
The game exports a file which contains variables such as:

```
$RL_PlayerScore_CurrentTrail_14911 = "lasergold";
$RL_PlayerScore_HasTrail_14911_LaserGold = 1;
$RL_PlayerScore_Money_14911 = 2148;
```

I'd like to convert these into an array like

```
$data = array(
'CurrentTrail_14911' => 'lasergold'
'HasTrail_14911_LaserGold' => '1'
'Money_14911' => '2184'
);
```

Is there any way I could do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could work with `$GLOBALS`, which stores the current script variables in an array, but this is not a good idea. Are you sure you cannot export the variables to another format (like CSV or something)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php << does exactly what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [return an array with all your declared variables](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php), and loop through them cutting off the desired piece of text. You could do something like this:

```
<?php
//echo your generated file here;
$generatedVars = get_defined_vars();
$convertedArray = array();
foreach($generatedVars as $key=>$var)
{
  $key = str_replace("RL_PlayerScore_","",$key);
  $convertedArray[$key] = $var;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Include file in scope and then get array of defined vars, excluding globals you don't need.

```
include('name-of-your-file.php');

$data = get_defined_vars();
$data = array_diff_key($data, array(
  'GLOBALS' => 1, 
  '_FILES' => 1, 
  '_COOKIE' => 1, 
  '_POST' => 1, 
  '_GET' => 1, 
  '_SERVER' => 1, 
  '_ENV' => 1, 
  'ignore' => 1 )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

If **all game variables** are going to begin with 'RL_PlayerScore_', you could use something like that :

```
$vars = [];

foreach($GLOBALS as $var => $value) {
    if(strpos($var, 'RL_PlayerScore_') === 0) {
        $vars[$var] = $value;
    }
}
```

`$vars` will be filled by all your variables.

See @Dagon comment also.